# PHP Characters filtered after website cleaning

Tags: php, code-injection

I'm managing the website http://www.continentevideo.com.ar , which suffered an injection in the past. I've used a script to clean it (can't remember the name right now), it worked, but on every page I have at the top like 20 PHP closing tags. You can see them by visiting the web.

How can I know where all those tags come from and remove it? I guess that those are PHP closing tabs, but I'm not 100% sure.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean about "know here all those tags come from?", who inserted it or where is the beginning of it?

Comment: I just want not to see those tags on the website, by removing them or by getting to know where is the beginning of it.

Comment: Taking a look into the website. It seems that is something that is not in .php or .html files, but either on database or some sort of static injection on template files, but since even the administration panel has it on top, I would go for static files. A crazy solution? Write piece of javascript that on document ready, finds that content on body. That should be the solution thought, but would remove that ugly until you find something definitive.

Comment: grep for '?>?>?>' - it should show you which file has the content

Comment: Follow the page execution and you should be able to figure out where it is coming from..

Comment: @FabianoAraujo do you have any link or something to look out how to find and replace text in javascript? Been trying to get it, but my head is a mess with my jobs. Thanks in advice!

Comment: @DaNoiseMan either `.indexOf()` or `.search()` should to the job. But again, that is a really alternative way to hide your problem, not solving it. It may also impact on performance and not being a real-time. You also have to find n times the `?>` content, so there is a logic to be build there.